# pandas: map new values based on first character

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dictionary, replace, dataframe

Is there a way to map new values onto a dataframe column based on the first character of the current values.

My current code:

```
ncesvars['urbantype'] = np.where(ncesvars['urbantype'].str.startswith('1'), 'city', ncesvars['urbantype'])
ncesvars['urbantype'] = np.where(ncesvars['urbantype'].str.startswith('2'), 'suburban', ncesvars['urbantype'])
ncesvars['urbantype'] = np.where(ncesvars['urbantype'].str.startswith('3'), 'town', ncesvars['urbantype'])
ncesvars['urbantype'] = np.where(ncesvars['urbantype'].str.startswith('4'), 'rural', ncesvars['urbantype'])
```

I was thinking about using some sort of `dict` and then `pd.replace`, but wasn't sure how to do that with `.str.startswith()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a dict of your categories, use `str[0:1]` to slice the data and call `map` on a boolean mask of your `Series` by testing whether the data's first character is in your dict keys so that only matches will be overwritten otherwise you overwrite with `NaN` as there is no mapping for the last row in the following example:

```
In [16]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'urbantype':['1 asdas','2 asd','3 asds','4 asdssd','5 asdas']})
df

Out[16]:
  urbantype
0   1 asdas
1     2 asd
2    3 asds
3  4 asdssd
4   5 asdas

In [18]:
d = {'1':'city','2':'suburban', '3': 'town','4':'rural'}
df.loc[df['urbantype'].str[0:1].isin(d.keys()), 'urbantype'] = df['urbantype'].str[0:1].map(d)
df

Out[18]:
  urbantype
0      city
1  suburban
2      town
3     rural
4   5 asdas
```

Comment: thanks for the input. is the `df.loc` part important, compared to @ayhan's answer?

Comment: Yes because you only want to affect the rows where the data matches your dict keys, otherwise you overwrite that row with `NaN` this is why the last row is unchanged

Answer (score 3):

try something similar to:

```
ncesvars['urbantype'] = ncesvars['urbantype'].replace({
    r'^1.*', 'city', 
    r'^2.*', 'suburban'},
    regex=True)
```

Test:

```
In [32]: w
Out[32]:
     word
0    1_A_
1  word03
2  word02
3  word00
4    2xxx
5  word04
6  word01
7  word02
8  word04
9    3aaa

In [33]: w['word'].replace({r'^1.*': 'city', r'^2.*': 'suburban', r'^3.*': 'town'}, regex=True)
Out[33]:
0        city
1      word03
2      word02
3      word00
4    suburban
5      word04
6      word01
7      word02
8      word04
9        town
Name: word, dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks for the input. I receive the erorr `replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'regex'` and when i try it without the `regex` argument i receive the error `replace() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)`

Comment: does not work for me either, I receive the original values

Comment: @As3adTintin, i've added a test case